# libGDX: Get Specific Index of an Item from Multidimensional-Array Class

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, libgdx

In My game I created Multidimensional-Array from `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array` Class as the following:

```
private static final Array<Array<Actor>> ARRAY_COLS = new Array<Array<Actor>>();
```

[image]

Now, In `touchDown` method from `InputListener`, **H**ow can I get a specific actor from `ARRAY_COLS` AND it Index? which all I have the known actor `event.getTarget();` as the following:

```
InputListener listener = new InputListener() {
       public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) { 
           return true; 
       });
```

**EDIT**: How Can I get *index* of this actor?
like that `ARRAY_COLS.IndexOf(event.getTarget());` which the target is `ARRAY_COLS.get(_col).get(_row);` in the previous image case `_col == 3;` and `_row == 4;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, event *should* return the specific actor that was clicked. If not, try setting actor's `Touchable` status. If it returns the `Group` actor that contains the one you need, you can always try using `Actor#hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable)`, which takes local actor coordinates and should return an actor in the specific, clicked place. No need to store 2D array of actors, really.

Also, `Actor` has a `setName` method. Instead of a 2D array, you can use a `ObjectMap<String, Actor>` (also a lightweight LibGDX collection), give actors meaningful names and put the actors in the map during their initiation.

If you *need* a 2D array, you can use `setUserObject` to store the index values. I'm assuming you create the actor in nested `for` loops, so you can use a `Vector2`, `Point` or a simple class with two int variables storing the loop indexes. Then you can either serialize it to string and use as name or put as the user object and then retrieve it in the listener method.

For example:

```
public class IntPair { private final int x, y; /* Constructor, getters */ }

// Creation:
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        Actor actor = new Actor();
        actor.setUserObject(new IntPair(x, y));
    }
}

// Accessing index:
IntPair index = (IntPair) actor.getUserObject();
```

Comment: +1. I edited my question. Ya, I stored index in `UserObject`. then I can get index of actor easly. thanx for hint me.

Comment: @Crowni, If it solves your problem, I guess you can accept the answer.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer. ;)